# Angular version of KnockoutJS' way to bind to scope for field shortcuts

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js, with-statement

In knockout.js it's possible to bind to an observable object inside the ViewModel:

```
function MyViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  this.user = new User(data);
}
```

And use it like this in the View:

```html
<div data-bind="with: user">
  // we can do this
  <div data-bind="text: FirstName"></div>
  // instead of this
  <div data-bind="text: user.FirstName"></div>
</div>
```

Is there an equivalent of this in Angular?

Comment: Is this just so you can write `FirstName` instead of `user.FirstName`? I don't think it is possible. The "Controller As" syntax (Google it) might give you some of what you want.

Comment: I don't think `ControllerAs` has anything to do (if nothing else it **adds** a level). There is nothing like this in Angular (for now), but I am pretty sure you can write a directive or something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Proof-Of-Concept example, I hacked together a small directive to do what you asked for.

---

**DISCLAIMER**:
It is just a Proof-Of-Concept demo and by no means is it thoroughly tested or guaranteed to work as expected in all cases. Yet, I believe it proves what you want is doable (with just a few lines of code) and even works inside forms (which is a useful and widely used feature).

---

So, here it is (scroll to the bottom for a live demo):

```
.directive('ngModelWith', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        template: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
            var prefix = tAttrs.ngModelWith ? tAttrs.ngModelWith + '.' : '';
            if (prefix) {
                angular.forEach(tElem.children(), function (child) {
                    if (child.hasAttribute('ng-model')) {
                        child.setAttribute('ng-model', 
                                prefix + child.getAttribute('ng-model'));
                    }
                });
            }
            return tElem.html();
        }
    };
});
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
<div ng-model-with="user">
    <input type="text" name="first" ng-model="firstName" required />
    <input type="text" name="last"  ng-model="lastName"  required />
</div>

$scope.user = {
    firstName: '...',
    lastName:  '...'
};
```

or even put it inside a `form`/`ngForm`:

```
<div ng-form="form1">
    <div ng-model-with="user">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

---

<sub>**Note:**
For the sakes of simplicity and brevity, I ignore alternative forms of defining a directive, e.g. `ng:model`, `data-ng-model`, `x-ng-model` etc.

You need to either make sure you always use `ng-model` on elements inside of an `ngModelWith` parent or enhance the directive to look for all alternatives (which isn't that complex anyway).</sub>

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/ysmE2/)**.

Comment: Seems like there should be an alternative baked into Angular. I mean this has got to be a standard need after all.

Comment: @jwize: It's so easy to add it that it probably isn't worth it :D That's the power of Angular !